# How to use ggplot with prop.table(table(x)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

First, I have a data with two categorical variables into like this:

```
nombre <- c("A","B","C","A","D","F","F","H","I","J")
sexo <- c(rep("man",4),rep("woman",6))
edad <- c (25,14,25,76,12,90,65,45,56,43)
pais <- c(rep("spain",3),rep("italy",4),rep("portugal",3))

data <- data.frame(nombre=nombre,sexo=sexo,edad=edad,pais=pais)
```

If I use:

```
prop.table(table(data$sexo,data$pais), margin=1)
```

I can see the relative frequency of the levels, for example for `Italy` `(Man=0.25 Woman=0.5)`

but the problem is that when I try to plot the `prop.table(table(x))` I get something different

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(prop.table(table(data),margin=1)), aes(x=pais ,y =Freq, fill=sexo))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

On the `Y` axis from 0 to 3 and for example in the bar `Italy` `(Woman=2 Man=2.5)`
I don't need that (and I don't know what is showing), I want the same with as I had with the table of the `prop.table(table(x))`

I think the problem is something related with the margin=1

Thanks you!

Comment: inside the ggplot, it should be prop.table(table(data$sexo,data$pais), margin=1) ?

Comment: Please lookup the position parameter of `geom_bar`. By default, it is `"stack"`. This means that these proportions are added on top of each other. Change it to `"identity"` and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the same table

```
tab = prop.table(table(data$sexo,data$pais), margin=1)
tab = as.data.frame(tab)
```

Then plot:

```
ggplot(tab,aes(x=Var2,y=Freq,fill=Var1)) + geom_col()
```

Or simply:

```
barplot(prop.table(table(data$sexo,data$pais), margin=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like `position = "dodge"`

If I run the following on your data :

```
P <- prop.table(table(data$sexo,data$pais), margin=1)
ggplot(as.data.frame(P), aes(x = Var2, y = Freq, fill = Var1)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge")
```

I output the following graph :

[image]